# Data precision in Stata

Tags: precision, floating-accuracy, stata, floating-point-precision

This is the trivial problem and I just wanted to know what is happening here.

Following is my sample data for which I am trying to find the row max in `stata`

```
  x1            x2             x2
70001102    70001102    70001102
70001102    70001102    70001102
```

Now, I used the following code to find the `row max:`

```
egen maxi rmax(x1 x2 x3)
```

However, on the data sheet I find the rmax for first and second rows to be 70001104 which is obviously not true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `egen double maxi = rmax(x1 x2 x3)`, or `egen double maxi = rowmax(x1 x2 x3)`. A long would also work in this case.

Here are the limits for the various storage types:

```
     type                   minimum                 maximum
     ------------------------------------------------------
     byte                      -127                     100
     int                    -32,767                  32,740
     long            -2,147,483,647           2,147,483,620
     ------------------------------------------------------
     float              -16,777,216              16,777,216
     double  -9,007,199,254,740,992   9,007,199,254,740,992
```

You can learn more about precision [on the Stata blog](http://blog.stata.com/tag/precision/)

Also, the second x2 in the data should be an x3 up there.

Comment: `rmax()` manifestly still works, but `rowmax()` has been the documented name as an `egen` function since Stata 9.

Comment: Nick's correct: rmax is just wrapper for rowmax. I will amend my answer.